# Python- handling warning and critical parameters with getopt

Tags: amazon-web-services, nagios

I'm trying to write a script to alert on certain warning and critical levels. So far it only shows ok no matter the output. It ignores warning and critical. What do I need to change?

./check_sqs -p prefix -q queue -s xxx -a xxx -w 5 -c 10

OK: depth = 33;| Prefix_Queue=33

```
for o, a in opts:
    if o in ('-q', '--queue'):
        queue_name = a
    if o in ('-a', '--access_key'):
        access_key = a
    if o in ('-s', '--secret_key'):
        secret_key = a
    if o in ('-p', '--prefix'):
        prefix = a
    if o in ('-w', '--warning'):
        warning = a
    if o in ('-c', '--critical'):
        critical = a

if access_key == "_none_":
    c = SQSConnection()
else:
    c = SQSConnection(access_key, secret_key)

cnt = 0
if queue_name != '':
    q = c.get_queue(queue_name)
    if q == None:
        print "ERROR: Invalid queue name " + queue_name
        sys.exit(3)
    cnt = q.count()
    if cnt >= critical:
        print 'Critical: depth =', str(cnt) + ';|', q.id.split('/')[2] + "=" + str(cnt)
        sys.exit(2)
    if cnt >= warning:
        print 'Warning: depth =', str(cnt) + ';|', q.id.split('/')[2] + "=" + str(cnt)
        sys.exit(1)
    if isinstance(cnt, int) and cnt >= 0:
        print 'OK: depth =', str(cnt) + ';|', q.id.split('/')[2] + "=" + str(cnt)
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print 'Unknown: depth =', str(cnt) + ';|', q.id.split('/')[2] + "=" + str(cnt)
        sys.exit(3)

rs = c.get_all_queues()
resp = ''
for q in rs:
    name = q.id.split('/')[2]
    if name.startswith(prefix):
        cnt = cnt + q.count()
        resp = resp + name + "=" + str(q.count()) + " "
print 'OK: depth =', str(cnt) + ';|', resp
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: You have two OK blocks that return the same message.  Make them distinct and see which one is firing; that will give you more information.  For debugging, also print out the values and types of 'critical' (etc) before the comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that was very helpful. Critical and Warning are strings, and that's why the comparison was not working. Changing them into int made the trick.

critical = int(critical)
warning = int(warning)